# Varying pagination in different formats of a report

Tags: jasper-reports

Using iReport, I am generating reports to be viewed in multiple formats. Is it possible for me to **ignore pagination** only for particular formats like HTML and let it be `true` for the rest?

With `isIgnorePagination="false"` the HTML preview appears in chunks. However, setting it to `true` makes the PDF output a single page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why yes you can. Add the the `IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION` with the appropriate value before you export your report. You can set the value at run time based on what your export format is.

```
params.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It became evident that it was impossible to do it with iReport alone.

Comment: I found these links [link1](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/nopagebreak/index.html) & [link2](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=30269) very helpful.

Comment: Well right, it has to happen at run time. You can set it one way or another at design time in iReport, but that will not get you what you want. You will have to do it before you actually export by adding it to the Map of parameters you pass into the report.

Comment: Also, the problem with the `Suppress Pagination Examples` in your link1 is that I believe it will still print the page headers and footers each time. Generally what you really want is for them to printed once when you export to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution for this problem:

```
        paramaters.put("fromDate", fromDate);
        paramaters.put("toDate", toDate);
        if (!output.equals("pdf"))
        {
        paramaters.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", true);
        }
        else
            paramaters.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", false);


        JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(CompiledReport, paramaters, connection);


        if (output.equals("html")) {
            generateHtmlResponse(response, jasperPrint);
        } else if (output.equals("pdf")) {
            generatePdfResponse(response, jasperPrint);
        } else if(output.equals("excel")) {
            generateXLResponse(response, jasperPrint);
        }
```